# How do I "printf" an array of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, printf

Basically, I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   string energy[9] ={"1E4","3E4","1E5","3E5","1E6","3E6","1E7","3E7","1E8"};

   for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
   {
     //printf("%s\n", energy[j]);
     //cout << energy[j] << endl;
   }
}
```

And I would like to "printf" every element of the array of string with printf just like the "cout" command does. I have tried pointers to the first element of array and some other technics but I cannot make it work. What do I need to put in printf and why what is currently in my printf does not work?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use printf?

Comment: Vennor answered my question but just to let you know, it's simply because I want to open a file which contain one of these strings and I know that the syntax is similar to printf.

Comment: This may be easier with `std::cout`:  `std::cout << energy[j] << "\n";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf` expects `char*` type, but you're passing `std::string` in. Use `data()` or `c_str()` function to extract underlying char array pointer from the string.

```cpp
printf("%s\n", energy[j].data());
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I can't believe I missed. Especially since another piece of my code has the c_str() in it and I completely forgot about that. It's getting late :D Thanks again for that quick answer.